# Find all positive integers $a$ and $b$ satisfying $\gcd (a,b)=10$ and $\operatorname{lcm} (a,b)=100$ simultaneously.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, gcd-and-lcm, least-common-multiple

Find all positive integers $a$ and $b$ satisfying
$$\gcd (a,b)=10$$
and 
$$\operatorname{lcm} (a,b)=100$$
simultaneously.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: $100$ only has nine divisors....if you can't think of anything else, just work with that list.

Comment: and you need to consider only those that are multiples of $10$

Answer (score 2):

WLOG

$\dfrac aA=\dfrac bB=10;(A,B)=1$

$[a,b]=[10A,10B]=10[A,B]=100$

$\implies[A,B]=?$ with $(A,B)=1$

Answer (score 2):

From the given,

$$a=10n,b=10m$$ where $n,m$ are relative primes and $$10nm=100.$$

Hence from the factorizations of $10$, the solutions

$$10,100;20,50;50,20;100,10.$$